# Missing move in a chess match due to lousy annotation

Tags: retrograde-analysis

I am a beginner in championships (well, and in chess in general). The other day I played a match that I can't analyze because there is an error in the annotation sheet.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Bc4 d5 5. Bb3 Nf6 6. d4 Bg4 7. O-O Nxe4 8. dxe5 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 Nxe5 10. Qd1 c6 11. Nc3 Bc5 12. Nxe4 dxe4 13. Qxd8+ Rxd8 14. Ba4 O-O 15. b3 Ng4 16. Bg5 Rd2 17. Bxd2 b5 18. Be3 Nxe3 19. fxe3 Bxe3+ 20. Kh1 f5 21. b4 bxa4 22. Rfd1 f4 23. Rd6 f3 24. Re1 f2 25. Rf1 Rc8 26. g4 c5 27. Rxa6 cxb4 28. Rxa4 Rxc2 29. Rxb4 Rxa2 30. Rxe4 Re2 31. h4 Re1 32. Kg2 null 33. Rxe3 Ra1 34. Ra2 Ra5 35. h5 h6 36. Ke4 Rg6 37. Kf6 Kh7 38. Re6 Ra5 etc.
```

I have Black's 32nd move recorded as Rf2, but that is wrong. Is it possible to fix this?

[Update] I uploaded scans of the match. It's in Spanish meaning that

- C is Knight
- A is Bishop
- R is King (which made me commit mistakes for rook)
- T is Rook
- D is Queen

[image: 1/2]

[image: 2/2]

Comment: I have taken the moves you gave and put them into the replayer. As you can see if you click through there are several errors after move 32. Unless you can correct more of these moves it is unlikely that anybody else will be able to reconstruct your game.

Comment: @Brian: Maybe, maybe not, I literarely just reconstructed a tournament game from the lousy tinted copy. :-) But I saw that game partially. I looked at the rest of the moves, this seems indeed hopeless. Original poster: do you have a scan?

Comment: Sure, thanks for answering me. The (additional) problem is that notation is in Spanish. But I'll upload it when I have the chance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. If the move was 32...Re2 (perhaps making 33...Ra1 a wrongly notated move which was replaced by the correct Ra2), then I question why you didn't play 33...Rxe3. But if it was anything else, then I question why White wouldn't play 34.Rxa1.

So I think there were multiple missed moves at this spot in the notation. For example, maybe this was played:

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "63"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Bc4 d5 5. Bb3 Nf6 6. d4 Bg4 7. O-O Nxe4 8. dxe5 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 Nxe5 10. Qd1 c6 11. Nc3 Bc5 12. Nxe4 dxe4 13. Qxd8+ Rxd8 14. Ba4 O-O 15. b3 Ng4 16. Bg5 Rd2 17. Bxd2 b5 18. Be3 Nxe3 19. fxe3 Bxe3+ 20. Kh1 f5 21. b4 bxa4 22. Rfd1 f4 23. Rd6 f3 24. Re1 f2 25. Rf1 Rc8 26. g4 c5 27. Rxa6 cxb4 28. Rxa4 Rxc2 29. Rxb4 Rxa2 30. Rxe4 Re2 31. h4 Re1 32. Kg2 Re2 33. Kf3 Ra2 34. Rxe3
```

After all, we know a Kf3 was likely missed, because there's a later Ke4 and the king had to get there somehow. Ultimately you're the one who played the game; see if that rings a bell in your memory as something which might have happened.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. Thank!

Comment: He lost one rook and finally I promoted the h pawn

Answer (score 1):

Judging by how the game continues, I think the White rook f1 must have been captured around this time. That leads me to believe that rook f2 was in fact rook takes f1, taking off that rook. There are some irregularities in the moves that follow, however, I think this may have been the sequence of moves, consistent with the remaining moves later:

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "63"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Bc4 d5 5. Bb3 Nf6 6. d4 Bg4 7. O-O Nxe4 8. dxe5 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 Nxe5 10. Qd1 c6 11. Nc3 Bc5 12. Nxe4 dxe4 13. Qxd8+ Rxd8 14. Ba4 O-O 15. b3 Ng4 16. Bg5 Rd2 17. Bxd2 b5 18. Be3 Nxe3 19. fxe3 Bxe3+ 20. Kh1 f5 21. b4 bxa4 22. Rfd1 f4 23. Rd6 f3 24. Re1 f2 25. Rf1 Rc8 26. g4 c5 27. Rxa6 cxb4 28. Rxa4 Rxc2 29. Rxb4 Rxa2 30. Rxe4 Re2 31. h4 Re1 32. Kg2 Rxf1 33. Rxe3 Ra1 34. Kxf2 Ra2+ 35. Kf3 Ra5 36. h5 h6 37. Ke4 Rg5 38. Kf4 Kh7 39. Re6 Ra5 40. Ke4 Ra4+ 41. Ke5 Rxg4
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. It makes sense, not doubt. Thanks!